# RegEx - match minimum two words

Tags: regex

I would like to see if a string contains minimum two specific words.

eg.:
words to look for: `good, day, hello`

```
Match: What a good day
No match: What a day
Match: Hello and good day
```

So there should be at least two words in the string for the match to be..

For now I have: `/(good)|(day)|(hallo)/gmi`

but that makes a match if just one word is pressent.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can brute force all the combinations along with positive lookaheads:

```
^(?:(?=.*good)(?=.*day)|(?=.*good)(?=.*hello)|(?=.*day)(?=.*hello)).*$
```

> Notice with lookaheads, the order of the word appearance doesn't matter.

Here's how it looks:

[Test cases](https://regex101.com/r/lSkF9b/2/)

---

#### Edit

Assuming text like `good good` is not allowed, and inspired by [Michał Turczyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65574970/10289265) it can be simply as:

```
^.*(good|day|hello).*(?!\1)(?1).*$
```

Or if you're using non-pcre regex engine such as javascript

```
^.*(good|day|hello).*(?!\1)(?:good|day|hello).*$
```

See the results [here](https://regex101.com/r/lSkF9b/3/)

Comment: Yes, this looks good.. Can it test the whole text? It looks like the line break breaks the chain.

Comment: @Jesper I'm not quite sure what you mean. It treats each line as a new match if `m` flag is applied.

Comment: Nice use of reference to capture groups :)

Comment: @HaoWu I would like all the text to be testet as one line. So it has to ignore the line breaks.

Comment: @Jesper In that case you need to remove `m` flag and replace `.*` to `[\s\S]*`: https://regex101.com/r/lSkF9b/4

Answer (score 1):

You could try `^.*(?:good|day|hello).*(?:good|day|hello).*$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a line

`.*` - match zero or more of any characters,

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`good|day|hello` - alternation, match one from list,

`$` - match end of a line,

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g6CcEe/1)

Comment: @HaoWu In this solution it would.

Comment: I think I found a way to fix that if that is not allowed based on your answer.